# Accessing SmartArt shapes when the SmartArt is inside a Placeholder (PowerPoint 2007)

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I need to go through each shape of a smart-art in PowerPoint 2007.
When `shape.Type=msoSmartArt` then I could simply go through the shapes in shape.GroupItems.

However, when `shape.Type == msoPlaceholder && shape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType==msoSmartArt`
then `shape.GroupItems` is empty. How can I access the Smart Art shapes in such a case?

---

I used to think of VBA and C# VSTO as basically the same.

Well - here there's a difference. I tried Otaku's code in actual VBA and it indeed seems to work (sorry for the confusion, Otaku).

However, my program is in C# VSTO, and:

```
foreach (Shape slideShape in pres.Slides[1].Shapes)
{
  if (slideShape.Type != MsoShapeType.msoSmartArt &&   !(slideShape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPlaceholder &&  slideShape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType==MsoShapeType.msoSmartArt))
 continue;

 GroupShapes shapes=slideShape.GroupItems;
 Debug.WriteLine(shapes.Count);
}
```

Does produce: `shapes.Count=0` (when the shape type is Placeholder, and containedtype is SmartArt).

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really... but I did mark the answer as Useful as it works in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I use is copying the SmartArt and pasting it back.
the pasted SmartArt now has all its shapes in its GroupItems.
After working with these, I delete the pasted shape.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GroupShapes`, like:

```
Sub GetSAfromPlaceholder()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim sl As Slide: Set sl = ap.Slides(2)
    Dim sh As Shape: Set sh = sl.Shapes(2)
    Dim gsh As GroupShapes: Set gsh = sh.GroupItems
    If sh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If sh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoSmartArt Then
        Debug.Print "SmartArt Shape Count: " & gsh.Count
          For i = 1 To gsh.Count
            If gsh(i).TextFrame.HasText Then
                Debug.Print gsh(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not seem to help. When:
shape.Type == msoPlaceholder && shape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType==msoSmartArt

You get empty gsh. (gshCount=0)

A workaround is to copy the Smartart and paste it. The pasted shape will have GroupItems with all the actual shapes. However, this workaround is somewhat messy.

Comment: Maybe if I could somehow get from the placeholder its contained SmartArt Shape it might solve the problem. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. `gshCount` always equals more than 0. What I did was create a blank slide of *Two Content* layout, in both non-Title placeholders, I clicked the SmartArt icon and inserted SmartArt (different types in each one). I entered some text in some of the nodes. I've updated the code above to prove how it is working on myside (i.e. it only works if `sh.Type = msoPlaceholder` **and** `sh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoSmartArt`).